# Open a child div clicking in parent's one

Tags: jquery, click

I'm trying to create a "module" for joomla with custom HTML and JS.
I have 4 divs, each one with some information.
When I click in one of them, the information of the div I click must appear...
The problem is, how do I have to do for making it appear; only the information of the div I clicked... (?)
This is the code:

HTML

```
<div class="datos-lunares">
    <div id="nueva" class="luna nueva">
        <h2>Luna nueva</h2>
        <div id="nueva-datos" class="datos close">
            <p>Ideal para cosecha de raíz.</p>
            <p>Retira las hojas y botones florales marchitos y secos.</p>
            <p>Rotura los sustratos consiguiendo suelos más aireados y sueltos.</p>
            <p>Disminuye la cantidad de agua en el riego.</p>
            <p>Desmaleza tu huerta eliminando las malas hierbas.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="menguante" class="luna menguante">
        <h2>Cuarto menguante</h2>
        <div id="datos-menguante" class="datos close">
            <p>Si tienes cultivos cuyos frutos son comestibles, recoléctalos,también es el período más propicio para recoger hortalizas de hoja.</p>
            <p>Aumenta la cantidad de agua en el riego.</p>
            <p>Trasplanta los cultivos que lo requieran.</p>
            <p>Si utilizas fertilizantes líquidos, aplícalos en esta etapa.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="creciente" class="luna creciente">
        <h2>Cuarto creciente</h2>
        <div id="datos-creciente" class="datos close">
            <p>Este período se considera propicio para sembrar y repicar las plantas cuyas partes comestibles están por encima de la tierra y dan frutos, como tomates,pimientos, guisantes, judías...</p>
            <p>Aplica fertilizantes y abonos con previo laboreo del suelo.</p>
            <p>Disminuye la cantidad de agua en el riego.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="llena" class="luna llena">
        <h2>Luna llena</h2>
        <div id="datos-llena" class="datos close">
            <p>Siembra los vegetales cuya parte comestible crece bajo la tierra (zanahoria, patata, cebolla, etc).</p>
            <p>Abona los cultivos con estiércol y restos de materia vegetal.</p>
            <p>Aplica insecticidas orgánicos, esta fase es la más oportuna para controlar las plagas.</p>
            <p>Riega sin mojar las yemas y botones florales.</p>
            <p>Se sugiere realizar los injertos,trasplantes y podas.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(this, ".luna").click(function() {
        if (jQuery(".datos").hasClass("close")) {
            jQuery(".datos").show("slow");
            jQuery(".datos").removeClass("close");
            jQuery(".datos").addClass("open");
        } else {
            jQuery(".datos").hide("slow");
            jQuery(".datos").removeClass("open");
            jQuery(".datos").addClass("close");
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want something like an accordion:

```
$('.luna > h2').on('click', function(){

    $(this).next('.datos').slideToggle();
    //Or
    $(this).next('.datos').toggleClass('close open');

});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/an5f4uv1/1/)

You can also have a look at [jQuery UI Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

**Update**

To close all other divs when one is clicked you can do the following:

```
var next = $(this).next('.datos');
$('.datos').not(next).each(function(){
    $(this).slideUp();
});
next.slideToggle();
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zq00w81p/1/)

Comment: How could I close the div I opened just opening another one?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `jQuery(this)` to interact with the object you're actually in.
2. Then, `find` the class `'datos'`
3. Finally, do what you need ...

Something like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery(".luna").on('click', function() {

        var $datos = jQuery(this).find(".datos");

        if ($datos.hasClass("close")) {

            $datos.show("slow").removeClass("close").addClass("open");

        } else {

            $datos.hide("slow").removeClass("open").addClass("close");

        }

    });

});
```

See snippet example:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        jQuery(".luna").click(function() {

            var $datos = jQuery(this).find(".datos");

            if ($datos.hasClass("close")) {

                $datos.show("slow").removeClass("close").addClass("open");

            } else {

                $datos.hide("slow").removeClass("open").addClass("close");

            }

        });

    });
```

```css
.luna h2 {
  color: red
}
.datos {
  display: none
}
.datos.open {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="datos-lunares">
    <div id="nueva" class="luna nueva">
        <h2>Luna nueva</h2>
        <div id="nueva-datos" class="datos close">
            <p>Ideal para cosecha de raíz.</p>
            <p>Retira las hojas y botones florales marchitos y secos.</p>
            <p>Rotura los sustratos consiguiendo suelos más aireados y sueltos.</p>
            <p>Disminuye la cantidad de agua en el riego.</p>
            <p>Desmaleza tu huerta eliminando las malas hierbas.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="menguante" class="luna menguante">
        <h2>Cuarto menguante</h2>
        <div id="datos-menguante" class="datos close">
            <p>Si tienes cultivos cuyos frutos son comestibles, recoléctalos,también es el período más propicio para recoger hortalizas de hoja.</p>
            <p>Aumenta la cantidad de agua en el riego.</p>
            <p>Trasplanta los cultivos que lo requieran.</p>
            <p>Si utilizas fertilizantes líquidos, aplícalos en esta etapa.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="creciente" class="luna creciente">
        <h2>Cuarto creciente</h2>
        <div id="datos-creciente" class="datos close">
            <p>Este período se considera propicio para sembrar y repicar las plantas cuyas partes comestibles están por encima de la tierra y dan frutos, como tomates,pimientos, guisantes, judías...</p>
            <p>Aplica fertilizantes y abonos con previo laboreo del suelo.</p>
            <p>Disminuye la cantidad de agua en el riego.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="llena" class="luna llena">
        <h2>Luna llena</h2>
        <div id="datos-llena" class="datos close">
            <p>Siembra los vegetales cuya parte comestible crece bajo la tierra (zanahoria, patata, cebolla, etc).</p>
            <p>Abona los cultivos con estiércol y restos de materia vegetal.</p>
            <p>Aplica insecticidas orgánicos, esta fase es la más oportuna para controlar las plagas.</p>
            <p>Riega sin mojar las yemas y botones florales.</p>
            <p>Se sugiere realizar los injertos,trasplantes y podas.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

### Edit (Clarification):

I did not realize that you are using `this` on the assignment of that `click` event...
... Actually, it is possible to pass a second parameter to the constructor, to avoid `find ()` function, but you must use it in the nested object and not the container.

Ex.

```
jQuery(".luna").on('click', function() {
    if (jQuery(".datos", this).hasClass("close")) { /*...*/ });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

kindly use

```
$(this).find( "div" ).show("slow");
```

to show the div.

Answer (score -1):

The way I see it, you're missing CSS to define the way the information block should display when it has the class `close` and `open`, unless you have some CSS linked to the document that you haven't mentioned.

So you would end up with something like this in the CSS file:

```
.close
{
    display: none;
}

.open
{
    display: block;
}
```

Or to be more specific and avoid potential conflicts with other elements on the page with the `close/open` classes:

```
.datos.close
{
    display: none;
}

.datos.open
{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: It would help greatly if you would provide a comment as to why you think this answer is incorrect, instead of being a downvote danny...

Comment: In OP question, you can read: ***only the information of the div I clicked...***  So it's a `click event` related question, not `CSS`.